# Any way to update OCZ SSD firmware without internet?

Tags: ssd, firmware

I've downloaded their PC Bootable tools, created a bootable disk, then reboot, run firmware update command... and it says "no internet connection". Dead end.
Any way to update firmware from pre-downloaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found was to create an additional installation of Windows (on another disk), boot from it and run OCZ toolkit there.

Answer (score 0):

If on linux and your ocz is on another drive and booting on usb does not detect wifi/lan connection

You can

- download the windows version of the firmware
- unzip it
- using `wine` to run it